# Exercise 8, Section 3.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing

> Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$ and $T$ a linear operator on $V$. If $T^2 = 0$, what can you say about the relation of the range of $T$ to the null space of $T$?

We can prove a stronger result:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$ and $T\in L(V,V)$. Then $T^2=0$$\iff$$R_T\subseteq N_T$.

**My attempt:** Suppose $T^2=0$. Let $x\in V$. Then $T^2(x)=T(T(x))=0_V$. So $T(x)\in N_T$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we have $T(x)\in N_T$, $\forall x\in V$. Hence $R_T\subseteq N_T$. Conversely, suppose $R_T\subseteq N_T$. Let $x\in V$. Since $T(x)\in R_T\subseteq N_T$, we have $T(T(x))=0_V$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $T(T(x))=0_V$, $\forall x\in V$. Hence $T^2=0$. **Is my proof correct?**

---

We can even prove stronger result:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$ and $T,S\in L(V,V)$. If $R_S\subseteq N_T$, then $(ST)^2=0$.

**My attempt:** Let $x\in V$. Then $(ST)^2(x)$ $=ST(ST(x))$ $=ST(S(T(x)))$. Since $S(T(x))\in R_S\subseteq N_T$, we have $T(S(T(x)))=0_V$. So $ST(S(T(x)))$ $=S(T(S(T(x))))$ $=S(0_V)=0_V$. Thus $(ST)^2(x)=0_V$, $\forall x\in V$. Hence $(ST)^2=0$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: This isn't stronger. To make it stronger consider the statement: $R_S\subseteq N_T\iff T\circ S=0$.

Comment: @Mateo I meant to say, stronger in $(\Leftarrow)$ direction, because we can take $S=\text{id}_V$ so that $ST=T$.

Comment: Both of your proofs look good.

Comment: Yes. Both proofs are correct. $T^2=0$ means "$T$ is a nilpotent operator of degree $2$ " .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$ and $T$ a linear operator on $V$. If $T^2 = 0$, what can you say about the relation of the range of $T$ to the null space of $T$?

> We can prove a stronger result:

> > Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$ and $T\in L(V,V)$. Then $T^2=0$$\iff$$R_T\subseteq N_T$.

> **My attempt:** Suppose $T^2=0$. Let $x\in V$. Then $T^2(x)=T(T(x))=0_V$. So $T(x)\in N_T$.

You can end the proof here.

> Since $x$ was arbitrary, we have $T(x)\in N_T$, $\forall x\in V$.

You're merely repeating yourself here.

> Hence $R_T\subseteq N_T$. Conversely, suppose $R_T\subseteq N_T$. Let $x\in V$. Since $T(x)\in R_T\subseteq N_T$, we have $T(T(x))=0_V$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $T(T(x))=0_V$, $\forall x\in V$. Hence $T^2=0$. **Is my proof correct?**

I'm not sure what the point of this is.

> We can even prove stronger result:

> > Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$ and $T,S\in L(V,V)$. If $R_S\subseteq N_T$, then $(ST)^2=0$.

I don't think that is a "stronger result". $TS=0$ follows immediately from those definitions, so $(ST)^2=0$ seems to be just a magic carpet ride or something.

> **My attempt:** Let $x\in V$. Then $(ST)^2(x)$ $=ST(ST(x))$ $=ST(S(T(x)))$. Since $S(T(x))\in R_S\subseteq N_T$, we have $T(S(T(x)))=0_V$. So $ST(S(T(x)))$ $=S(T(S(T(x))))$ $=S(0_V)=0_V$. Thus $(ST)^2(x)=0_V$, $\forall x\in V$. Hence $(ST)^2=0$. **Is my proof correct?**

Yes it is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Btw $TS\neq ST$.